# Increase table view height based on content on scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

Hi I want increase tableview height dynamically on scrollview.
I will try the following code even also it is not working

Here items is tableview data array

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    rewardPointsApi()
    if(items != nil) {
        self.tableviewheight.constant = CGFloat(70*items.count)
    }
    tableviewheight.constant = tableview.contentSize.height
}
```

Comment: You want to increase table view's height to be equal to its contents, and handle scrolling using additional scroll view - why? Not only it doesn't make sense to perform some magic to achieve a functionality that is there out of the box, but it's also terribly ineffective and memory-consuming since it basically discards table view's cell reusal mechanism. What is the purpose of it?

Comment: ok I agree with you I having some data on view along scrollview on that time what we are doing.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes setting the constant with content size of tableview will not properly update the height because tableview is being reloading or calculating it self

**What would be best place ?**

If you have static data then probably `viewDidAppear` is the best place

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.heightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

  }
```

If your data is dynamic like calling the API. Then inside the response block inside main queue.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.heightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height 
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 }
```

**IMPORTANT** : Factor that matters directly with content size is `estimateRowHeight` So If you sure about height of your cell then you directly apply in case of static number of rows

Hope it is helpful to you and someone else who is facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

**Use the following code after getting a response from api**, first assign data to to item array then reload your table view and set height constraint of `UItableview`
and disable tableview self scroll see the below code.

```
if(items != nil)
{
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         tableView.reloadData()
         tableviewheight.constant = tableview.contentSize.height
         tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are writing above line right after `rewardPointsApi()` your logic will work if you are waiting for response on this method if its async request your code will not work.
You need to do add following line in response of `rewardPointsApi()` right after reloading data in tableView.

```
        tableviewheight.constant = tableview.contentSize.height
```

Answer (score 0):

In delegate method set height of constraint according table
view content size

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.constraint_height.constant = self.tblview.contentSize.height
}
```

after that reload and view layout if needed when get api response

```
 self.tblview.reloadData()
 self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 self.constraint_height.constant = self.tblview.contentSize.height
 self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```